# find the map which induces the homorphism between fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

Denote $X=\mathbb{R}P^2$ to be the 2-dimensional real projective space, see definition here [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space).

Also from the above link, we know that it has a CW complex structure with one 0-cell $x_0$, one 1-cell and one 2-cell.

Then suppose we have a group homomorphism $\phi: \pi_1(X,x_0)\rightarrow \pi_1(Y,y_0)$, where $Y$ is a path-connected space, prove that we can find a map $f:(X,x_0)\rightarrow (Y,y_0)$, such that $f_*=\phi.$

Remark: this is a special case of one homework, I know that we can first define a map $f:S^1\rightarrow Y$ to be $f(a)=b,$ where $\phi([a])=[b]$ and $S^1$ is the 1-cell, $[a]$ is the generator of $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}/{2\mathbb{Z}}$,  but how to extend it to the whole $X$, i.e., to the whole 2-cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key lemma for inductively defining mappings out of cell complexes: if the map $f_n$ is defined on the $n$-skeleton $X_n$ already, and you want to define it on an $n+1$-cell with attaching map $\phi: S^n \to X_n$, then you can do so if and only if $f_n \phi$ is nullhomotopic.

So you need to show that the attaching map from the circle to the 1-skeleton of $\mathbb{RP}^1$ becomes nullhomotopic after applying the map $f$ you've constructed so far, but that just says that $2[a]$ needs to be 0 on $Y$, which is true.

Comment: I have not learnt this key lemma, could you give me some reference for this?

Comment: Hatcher talks about it at the bottom of p. 90. Jason DeVito's answer is the proof of the lemma in this case (and his argument is what works in general).

Comment: Oh, I find that, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since $[b]$ is the image of $[a]$, and $[a]$ is 2-torision, $[b]$ must be 2-torsion.  That means that $2b$ is null homotopic.  Let $F:S^1\times I$ be such a null homotopy.  For definiteness, assume $F(x,0) = y_0$ and $F(x,1) = 2b$.

Since $F(x,0)$ is constant, $F$ descends to a map on $S^1\times I/$~ where we identify all points of the form $(x,0)$.  It's easy to see that $S^1\times I/$~ is homeomorphic to a disc $D$.

So, we have a map $\tilde{F}:D\rightarrow Y$ which maps the boundary circle of $D$ to $2b$.  It follows that $\tilde{F}$ descends to a map on $D/$~ where we now identify the antipodal points on the boundary of $D$.  But $D$ with these points identified is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$, we we finally get our map $\tilde{\tilde{F}}:\mathbb{R}P^2\rightarrow Y$.  This is the map you want.

Comment: This is essentially a proof of countinghaus's key lemma in a very special case.